# SQL: How do I check for records in one table that aren't in another?

Tags: sql-server, exists

I want to find records that are in one table but not in another.  Except the records aren't formed the same. So I'm wanting to determine the columns I want to use to compare against. I thought I had it worked out with the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working (Returns zero records)...

```
SELECT A.Name, A.Position, A.[Year]
  FROM TABLE A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (

 SELECT B.Name, B.Position, B.[Year]
   FROM TABLE B
)
```

Or should I be doing this with some kind of join? Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the `WHERE` clause to compare the two tables to one another:

```
SELECT A.Name, A.Position, A.[Year]
  FROM TABLE A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (

 SELECT B.Name, B.Position, B.[Year]
   FROM TABLE B
   WHERE B.Name = A.Name AND B.Position = A.Position AND B.[Year] = A.[Year]
)
```

Comment: sorry the B and C were typos I corrected it in the question thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want use all three columns to do the comparison you can use an anti-join.

```
SELECT A.Name, A.Position, A.[Year]
  FROM TABLE_A A
     LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B
     ON a.name = b.name
         and a.position = b.position 
         and a.[Year] = b.[Year]
WHERE
   b.name is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an left outer join on table b with a where clause looking for null values.

I am assuming that everything in the first query comes from table A and everything in the second comes from table B

```
Select A.Name, A.Position, A.[Year]
from A
Left Join B on A.Name = B.Name and A.Position = B.Position and A.[Year] = B.[Year]
where B.Name is Null
```